# Sonatype Nexus Professional Proxy Configuration

Tags: proxy, nexus, sonatype

Our project requires Nexus Professional to store and manage artefacts in a centralized repository hosted on Windows server. We were able to install Sonatype Nexus Professional in Windows workstation. However, I got stuck with Nexus' proxy configuration. A repository of type proxy is not able connect to the proxy server (i.e Proxy Blocked ).

Can some one help with configuration of proxy settings in Sonatype Nexus Professional in Windows?

Regs, Syam

Answer (score 1):

This is HTTP error 407, indicating that your corporate http proxy server requires credentials but either none were supplied or incorrect ones were supplied.

Go to "administration/server" in the Nexus web UI, and configure both "default http proxy settings (optional)", and within that "authentication (optional)".

Answer (score 0):

Most like your server is blocked to connect to the remote server via a proxy server or firewall.

Log into the server as the user running Nexus and confirm that you can ping the remote server first. Most likely that does not work.

Once you have fixed that it will either work or if required you will have to configure Nexus to connect via a proxy. This can be done on a Nexus global level as well as per repository.

Answer (score 0):

I could ping to the https proxy server. We have configured the Proxy settings - Override the HTTP proxy setting of proxy repository configurations.

IAS server requires proxy authentication with error message "Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied". Hope this is due to proxy server configuration.

Error Message says:

```
Unexpected response code while executing GET method [repositoryId="central", requestPath="/.meta/prefixes.txt", remoteUrl="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.meta/prefixes.txt"]. 
Expected: "SUCCESS (200)". Received: 407 : Proxy Authentication Required 
( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )
```

Regards,
Syam

Answer (score 0):

We have made the configuration updates as per your suggestion. 
Some how my user credentials is getting locked out due to fact that login attempt failes multiple times at proxy server... 
So will have to check with our manager & see if some thing can be done at the proxy server lever to over come the proxy authentication issue. 
We will keep you updated. Ultimarly we are plaing for cenralies nexus server